# how to stop an application if opened from chrome or safari browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-2.0

in .cs page i am checking the browser type used to run the applcation:

```
#region CheckBrowserType
    /// <summary>
    /// Check for the browser type used in TDB application
    /// </summary>
    void CheckBrowserType()
    {
       if ((Request.Browser.Browser == "IE")||(Request.Browser.Browser == "Firefox"))
            {
                IntBrowserType = 1;
            }
       else
            {
                IntBrowserType = 2;
            }
        }
    #endregion
```

On page load I am calling the function:

```
CheckBrowserType();
        if (IntBrowserType == 1)
        {
//here i wil be  showing the  login page tetx boxes
        }
        else if (IntBrowserType == 2)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Please re-open application in either Firefox or Internet Explorer')</script>");
        }
```

If a user logins with a chrome browser i am displaying alert message. Once i click the ok in the alert message I can still see the login page controls displayed.

How can stop that (if user opens the application in either chrome or safari)?

I should stop the login page being displayed.

I am using vs2005, c#,asp.net 2.0

Any help how to solve the problem would be great.

thanks

prince

Comment: Instead of winding up users of Chrome and Safari, how about writing your application properly so that it is browser agnostic?

Comment: its an  old  application developed in  2006 so now i cannot  be going that,

Comment: @prince23: Sorry to hear that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the alert, use this:

```
window.location = 'errorpage.html'
```

and create this new page containing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Response.Write as follows...

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
Response.Write("alert('Please re-open application in either Firefox or Internet Explorer');");
Response.End();
return; //for good measure!
```